# Diagonal of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I need help solving this problem:

> The diagonal of a rectangle is $18$ cm longer than the shorter leg. If the area is $168 \ \text{cm}^2$, find the dimensions of the rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Take shorter leg as '$x$'

Longer leg = $\sqrt{(x+18)^2-x^2}$

$168= \sqrt{(x+18)^2-x^2}(x)$. Solve for $x$. 
I hope $\sqrt{(x+18)^2-x^2}$ gives something pretty.;)

Or try out factorizing $168$, that makes sense and problem will be solved easily.

$168=7\times2^3\times3$

Comment: Please use $\cdot$ (which you get with \cdot ) for multiplication instead of periods.  Particularly if you just have one, it looks like a decimal point.  In some cases you might want $\times$, which you get with \times

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sure. I will use those from now.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints** Let's *name* the shorter leg, say let it be $a$. Then use Pythagorean theorem to determine the other one (say you call it $b$). Then the area is $ab$ (in cm${}^2$).

Comment: Diagonal is $18$ cm longer than shorter side.:)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ = length of shorter leg

Let $y$ = length of longer leg

Let $d$ = length of diagonal

$$d = x + 18$$
$$xy = 168\tag{Area}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = d^2 = (x+18)^2\tag{Pythagorean Theorem}$$